# Maintaining regression results on web server or locally

Tags: automated-testing

I have a set of test cases which are run on every release of the compiler. The regression logs have to be in readable format. I already have a script to extract information from the logs which gives the name of test and pass-fail result. Now I need to format these result so that they can viewed in version based manner, use the bug tracking system to insert bug numbers, filter. I'm planning to host a server for doing this. Is there a html template or a software which can make my life easier?

Answer (score 1):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) might be useful for you.  You can use it to run a test suite against a build and then display the test results in a variety of ways.  Jenkins can preserve the test results for each build so that you can look at the results of previous builds.